# Constructing a Subclass Object in a Completely Different Class

Tags: java, arraylist, subclass, extends

So lets say i have the following code.

```
public class ImageMaker {

  // Variables
  static ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();//all the shapes contained in the image

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    shapes.add(new Rect());  //here i want to add an object Rect
  }
}
```

and in a different class called Shape shown below. Now I want to add an object of type Rect to my shapes array list but i cannot as it says Rect cannot be resolved to a type. How can i implement this? Of course i have more instance variables and methods but i did not show them. Let me know if you need more info to answer. Thanks!

```
public class Shape {
  public class Rect extends Shape {

  //rect instance variables

  public Rect(){
    super();
    System.out.print("Youve made a rect within shape");
  }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to declare `Rect` as an inner class of `Shape`.

Comment: Yea i am trying to create an array list of different shapes in my main method in a separate class. How can i add an object that is both a rect and a shape into my array list is my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tsnorri mentioned in comment, you should simply declare `Rect`as class out of `Shape`one.

```
public class Shape {

}

public class Rect extends Shape {
    //rect instance variables
    public Rect(){
        super();
        System.out.print("Youve made a rect within shape");
    }
}
```

In case you want to learn more about nested classes in Java this is a good starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

**Edit (working example)**

In general I recommend you some reading about basics of OO programming and JAVA in general.

here's a working example of adding both `Shape` and `Rect` to an `ArrayList`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ImageMaker
{
    static ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();//all the shapes contained in the image

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        shapes.add(new Shape());
        shapes.add(new Rect());
    }

    public static class Shape {
        System.out.print("Created new Shape");
    }

    public static class Rect extends Shape {
        //rect instance variables
        public Rect(){
            super();
            System.out.print("You've made a rect within shape");
        }
    }
}
```

cheers

Comment: When i try this it says that Rect must be defined in its own file. Sorry i an a newbie to all of this.

Comment: It shouldn't hurt if it's in the separate file. Otherwise check out `static` approach from oracle link (or @plalx's answer)

Comment: the only problem is i need to keep an arrayList of many different shapes, some of type Rect and some of other types, i just showed one example of the type.

Comment: You can have many different files, each of them is unique class which `extends Shape` and simply keep them all in an array as you stated in your question.
Try implementing that, and if you experience any more issues either try searching on SO or post here exact error.

Comment: ok i think i figured it out but now how exactly do i construct the new rect. for example i tried 'shapes.add(Shape(new Rect()));' and it says Rect cannot be resoled to a type

Answer (score 0):

Make the class `static`:

```
public static class Rect extends Shape {
```

Then use `new Shape.Rect()`

However, that seems like poor use of nested classes and you should consider defining `Rect` outside `Shape` in it's own file.

Comment: But will adding the static modifier make all instances of Rect the same?

Comment: so what exactly does the static modifier here do? i'm just looking for a simple clarification because i am utterly confused.

Comment: @theCodenator I suggest that you read the part on static nested classes of this article https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html